# multiple category for UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have a class A in which I have the following:

```
@implementation UIToolbar (A)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];

}
@end
```

and I have a class B, which I have the following:

```
@implementation UIToolbar (B)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithWhite:10.0 alpha:1.0];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    self.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0];

}
@end
```

Question is why is it only the top level category called each time? I basically want to have a different UIToolbar color/configuration for each different UIViewController, how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and B are not classes, they're categories. Any given class can only have one implementation of a given method at a time. If you try to override a method in more than one category, which implementation you get is undefined. Indeed, it's not recommended to override methods in categories at all -- if you need to override, you should create a subclass.

Comment: so to change the color/background color of a UIToolbar in pre-iOS 5 you would need to have a subclass? if I have different color

Comment: Correct. You need to subclass, not create a category.

Comment: @adit I believe I've used UIToolbar's `tintColor` property in the (pre-iOS 5) past, though I don't have any code handy. This SO question/answer seems to confirm that it should work fine, though. Good tips in the author's answer, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3151549/643383

Answer (score 0):

When you use this implementation , this is all uitoolbar which are custom with the theme. 
If your application is developed under ios5, you can use method `setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:`.

If you develop under ios < 5 , you can implement an new class inherited from uitoolbar which have a custom drawRect.

Comment: this is for iOS 4, I am aware of the setBackgroundImage method for iOS 5... that's what I am doing right haivng a new class inherited from UIToolbar