# Change tint color of the toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, interface, toolbar, tint

I want to change the tint of the buttons in the toolbar.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151549/uitoolbar-tint-on-ios-4) but I don't know how to access the toolbar object...

Comment: r u using navigation controller??? use self.navigationBar in this case...

Comment: I am, but I don't know how to access the navigation controller in code...

Comment: you dont need to get the access to your navigation controller object... u can access the navigationbar directly... look at my answer below.

Comment: Place an image and show the IBOutlet instance in your .h file. To refer which object it is, UIToolbar or UINavigationControllr, UINavigationBar. As this are diff diff widgets so...

Comment: To access it check out the navigationItem and navigationController properties of your UIViewController - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.83 green:0.43 blue:0.57 alpha:0.5];
```

considering you are writing this line of code in your viewcontroller...

Comment: 1. Is that inside viewDidLoad
        
2. I have a navigationItem, but not a navigationBar

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Tint UIButton and UIBarButtonItem](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2011/02/10/tint-color-uibutton-and-uibarbuttonitem) hope that helps !